# Is it possible to specify multiple versions of java in the j2se tag in JNLP files?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jnlp, ria

I am looking to restrict the RIA application to java version 7 and 8.

```
<resources os="Windows">
<j2se version="1.7*,1.8*" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="512m" />
</resources>
```

I am trying to do something like the above.  My goal is to see if user has java 7 or 8 installed and run the application with the available version.  If the user has anything 1.9 and above, the application should not run.

Is this possible,  if so, what is the correct syntax to specify the versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources):

> "The j2se/java element specifies what Java Platform Standard Edition
>   Runtime Environment (JRE) versions an application is supported on, as
>   well as standard parameters to the Java Virtual Machine.  If several
>   JREs are specified, this indicates a prioritized list of the supported
>   JREs, with the most preferred version first."

```
<java version="1.8" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="512m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
<java version="1.7" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="512m"/>
```

Also note when an href attribute is specified, a vendor-specific JRE is requested (oracle in this case). If you do not want that or that an installation routine pops up (when there is no corresponding jre installed) then remove the `href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"`link...

You might also try [JaNeLa](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0) from andrew which verifies your JNLP file...

Comment: Thank you.  Let me try this out.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed the + since it would mean that also jre 9,10 ... would also be ok. But it should work like this.

Comment: You are right about the +.  But * would perhaps work, e.g. 1.8* for any version of 1.8.  For some reason, SO errors out on me when I upvote or mark as accepted answer.